# Broadcast Receiver for Android 9

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, communication

I have a custom Broadcast Receiver structure to communicate 2 different application. I know its deprecated for Android 9. Are there any way to use my custom Broadcast Receiver on that device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"As part of the Android 8.0 (API level 26) Background Execution Limits, apps that target the API level 26 or higher can no longer register broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in their manifest."

I only changed my application targetSdkVersion 31 to 25 from gradle file. That worked for me.

---

Old gradle config

---

```
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }
```

---

New gradle config

---

```
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }
```